# hp printer install, start a new, how

Tags: 17.10, printing, scanner, devices, hplip

oke so i have new HP printer, this is what happend (so far)

HPLIP 3.17.7 was pre-installed
tried to install 3.17.11, but there were dependency issues so i left it for what is was as it wasn't really necessairy. 
i unpacked, linked to wifi and installed via HPLIP toolbox (first via USB, and then it was later added via WiFi)

all worked fine (then) except:

There were 2 printers (slightly differently named) and one fax installed under devices, While only 1 printer and 1 fax under HPLIP toolbox.

I tried to remove them and re-install them (the two printers just didn't seem right). but this morning i found there was only one printer left, the two under hplip toolbox were gone.

I also found out the printer didn't wake-up when an job was sent but it did print when i manually activated the printer.

i tried to re-install the printer via hplip toolbox but forgot to take out the usb so things were working, but via usb not wifi. In the mean time i also tried to scan.. which worked (mostly) but also via usb  ofcourse.

Now i took the usb away i found that there is just one printer under devices but i can't seem to have hplip to find the printers (while the setup runs normally) also the scanner is not found under xsane.

anyway i would love to start a new.

for that i believe i should: 
reset the printer.
remove all "instances" of the printer in ubuntu.
i would like to actually install hplip 3.17.11

but the last 2 i have problems with:
as the last remaining printer comes back if i remove it even with the printer powered off. i tried in devices and in cups!

about hplip version i'm in doubt, hp tells me there is support for 17.10 64 bit added, but why does ubuntu 17.10 then come with 3.17.7 instead. also the printer itself doens't really need it.

the error i get when trying to install is the following.

```
RUNNING PRE-INSTALL COMMANDS
----------------------------
OK


MISSING DEPENDENCIES
--------------------
Following dependencies are not installed. HPLIP will not work if all 
REQUIRED dependencies are not installed and some of the HPLIP features 
will not work if OPTIONAL dependencies are not installed.
Package-Name         Component            Required/Optional   
libcrypto            network              REQUIRED            
libnetsnmp-devel     network              REQUIRED            
sane-devel           scan                 REQUIRED            
pyqt4-dbus           gui_qt4              REQUIRED            
cups-devel           base                 REQUIRED            
reportlab            fax                  OPTIONAL            
cups-image           base                 REQUIRED            
python-notify        gui_qt4              OPTIONAL            
libjpeg              base                 REQUIRED            
dbus                 fax                  REQUIRED   

Do you want to install these missing dependencies (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y


INSTALL MISSING REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
-------------------------------------
note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: cups-devel (CUPS devel- Common 
Unix Printing System development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: cups-image (CUPS image - CUPS image development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libjpeg (libjpeg - JPEG library)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libcrypto (libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libnetsnmp-devel (libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: pyqt4-dbus (PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: dbus (DBus - Message bus system)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: sane-devel (SANE - Scanning library development files)


INSTALL MISSING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCIES
-------------------------------------
note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing OPTIONAL dependency for option 'gui_qt4': python-notify (Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications)
warning: Missing OPTIONAL dependency for option 'fax': reportlab 
(Reportlab - PDF library for Python)


CHECKING FOR NETWORK CONNECTION
-------------------------------
Network connection present.


RUNNING PRE-PACKAGE COMMANDS
----------------------------
sudo dpkg --configure -a (Pre-depend step 1)
sudo apt-get install --yes --force-yes -f (Pre-depend step 2)
sudo apt-get update (Pre-depend step 3)
OK


DEPENDENCY AND CONFLICT RESOLUTION
----------------------------------
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcups2-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Command failed. Re-try #1...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcups2-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Command failed. Re-try #2...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcups2-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Command failed. Re-try #3...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcups2-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100
Would you like to retry installing the missing package(s) (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ?
```

additionally

```
# hp-scan -g

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.17.7)
Scan Utility ver. 2.2

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

hp-scan[3467]: debug: getDeviceUri(None, None, ['hpaio'], {'scan- type': (<built-in function gt>, 0)}, , True)
hp-scan[3467]: debug: Mode=0
error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.
```

anyways, i would GREATLY appreciate help on all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Well for now i seem to have solved this issue by:

1) reset printer to factory setting
2) updated ubuntu to newest version (still 17.10) but a fresh install

```
# sudo do-release-upgrade -d

hplip:
  Installed: 3.17.10+repack0-4
  Candidate: 3.17.10+repack0-4
  Version table:
 *** 3.17.10+repack0-4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: good work; well done